# auto_update_statistics

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS off` for all user databases. If I issue this `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS of`f it works with no problem. If I use this

```
EXEC master..sp_MSForeachdb ' USE [?] IF ''?'' <> ''master'' AND ''?'' <> ''model'' AND ''?'' <> ''msdb'' AND ''?'' <> ''tempdb''
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE ?    SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS  OFF 
END'
```

it says:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 5, Line 1 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS' is not a
>   recognized SET option.

Comment: Your script is OK on SQL Server 2008. No error.

Comment: No error on SQL Server 2012 either.

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue but you should always enclose the database names in brackets. Like you did with your `USE [?]` statement. Change the `ALTER DATABASE ?` to `ALTER DATABASE [?]`.